# I Am Encountering An 400 Bad request Error In Wordpress While Making Call With wp_ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am working in a Wordpress project where I want to load something via ajax in my site. I am loading many sections via ajax, but I have never encountered an error before. Here, also, I am doing everything how it should be done, but I don't know why I am getting a 400 bad request error. Here is the code:

```
 if(!function_exists('enque_this')){
 function enque_this(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', MY_PLUGIN_LOCATION.'css/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('my_script_file',MY_PLUGIN_LOCATION.'js/md-referral.js','jQuery','',true);
    wp_localize_script('my_script_file','ajax_object',array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),'we_value'=>1234));
 }}
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enque_this');
   if(!function_exists('enque_single_prod_page')){
     function enque_single_prod_page(){
        wp_enqueue_script('my_script_file_2nd',MY_PLUGIN_LOCATION.'js/md-single.js','jQuery','',true);
        
     }}
      add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enque_single_prod_page');

function how_much_dis(){

        echo 'really .. . .!!! i Got SomeTHing ??';
};

add_action('wp_ajax_how_much_dis','how_much_dis');
```

jquery code

```
jQuery(document).on("click","#submit_reff_code",function(){
    
    var codes = jQuery("#input_reff_code").val(); 
    var button_text = jQuery("#submit_reff_code").val("Please Wait . . .");
    var is_disabled = jQuery('[name="add-to-cart"]').prop('disabled');
    var product_id = jQuery('[name="add-to-cart"]').val();
    var variation_id = jQuery('[name="variation_id"]').val();


        if( codes != "" &&  codes.length > 2 && is_disabled == false && jQuery.isNumeric(product_id)){

            var data = {
                'action' :  'how_much_dis',
                'product_id_from_prod' : product_id,
                'variation_id_from_prod': variation_id,
                'code'       : codes
            };
            jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data , function(response){
                
                    console.log(response);  

            });

        }else{
            alert("please enter valid code");
        };




});
```

Your help would be appreciated, thanxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

400 means that action is wrong. The code in the question should work when user is logged in. To make it working when user is not logged in, you have to add the line

`add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_how_much_dis','how_much_dis');`

Maybe this is the reason.

Comment: Yes Sir Thanx . .  Code IS Working When User Is  Logged In really thanxx for your reply sir